# Android background services example with interactive invoking for methods

Tags: android, service, background

I am not expert in android and I am looking for an example for an Android application which use a service in which there are real functional methods or in other words what a service could be useful for, when do we need it.Something beyond a simple services example..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure you're eager to get some working code, but if you're new to android a working example of a service will probably raise more questions...

I suggest familiarizing yourself with the types of background processes and determine which you need:

- [Brief explanation of Service versus AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957775/android-asynctask-vs-service)
- [Matrix of types of background processes](http://crazyaboutandroid.blogspot.com/2011/12/difference-between-android.html)

Here is an example of a Service:

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Here is an example of an AsyncTask

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Decide which type of background process you need, try to get it working and if it doesn't work post the code along with your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I do mean service and more specific remote service which communicate throw IPC with AIDL and IBinder, in fact .I don't really need the code itself but i need the idea of it because i am looking to do measurements on the IPC, but i need to have an application has this kind of services i mean a practical usage of the remote services known for developers

Comment: Oh I see.  I've never done that before but I found these with a quick search:

- [Detailed AIDL tutorial](http://app-solut.com/blog/2011/04/using-the-android-interface-definition-language-aidl-to-make-a-remote-procedure-call-rpc-in-android), [AIDL IPC RPC example (just code)](http://code.google.com/p/android-aidl-ipc-rpc-example), [Implementing Remote Interface Using AIDL](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/48.html).

You may want to create another topic or change this topic title so devs with this knowledge can find it.  Hope this helps a little =)

Comment: Yes It was helpful, i have to add some useful methods to the codes and try if it's work out! Thanks