# background task Works all the application life... Android

Tags: android, multithreading

it is logical question so I don't have code.
**My question is:**
How may I run background task that make Network work (waiting for messages from the server) and in the same time updates the UI when Message arrive!!
the Paradox "Android  prevent access to UI from another nonUI thread", and "prevent network accesss from UI thread!!!"
 **Important**: I want to run my method all the time that the application run, and scan network buffers and when I get message I want to update the UI and messages List...

Comment: use a `handler` and post to UI thread. simple example: http://crodrigues.com/updating-the-ui-from-a-background-thread-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a perfect description for a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). You can use `IntentService` or build your own `Service` (be careful, the last one doesn't start in a new thread by default).

There are also many examples out there how to update the UI from a Service (i.e. using [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) or [Broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695537/android-update-activity-ui-from-service)).

Answer (score 0):

Android provides built in class to perform network operation. For this purpose you can use `AsyncTask` class.

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

You can get details from here [Android AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

But if you want to check message continuously then Service is the best solution as @AlexS explained it perfectly.

Comment: `AsnycTask` is not meant for continually running in backgroud. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957775/android-asynctask-vs-service