# StopService onDestroy being called but service not ending

Tags: android, service, timer, handler, timertask

I try using TimerTask to download data from the server api, the task loops in background app.

I have a service class:

```
public class RequestNewInvoice extends Service {

    private Timer timer;
    private CheckTask checkTask;
    private Handler handler;
    private JSONParser jsonParser;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;   
    private boolean startService = true;

    private void init(){     
        this.handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.e("Message: ",msg.obj+"");
                return false;
            }
        });

        this.timer = new Timer();
        this.checkTask = new CheckTask();
        this.startService = true;
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(checkTask, 5000, 20 * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
        init();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("SERVICE STOP", "true");
        startService = false;
        checkTask.cancel();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
    }

    private class CheckTask extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            funcCheckInvoice();
        }
    }

    public void funcCheckInvoice(){
        try{
            if(startService){            
               Log.e("SERVICE START", "true");
               HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
               HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, SuperVAR.GET_CURRENT_SHIPMENT_TIMEOUT);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, SuperVAR.GET_CURRENT_SHIPMENT_TIMEOUT);

                httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SuperVAR.URL_GET_LIST_INVOICE_IN_CURRENT_SHIPMENT+"?"+ URLEncodedUtils.format(_REQUEST, "utf-8")+"unused="+System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);

                httpGet.setHeader("token",token);
                httpGet.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
                httpGet.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                jsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONFromRESPONSE(httpEntity);


                if(jsonObject == null){
                        Message message = Message.obtain();
                        message.obj = "get null.... internet like shit T_T";
                        handler.sendMessage(message);
                }else {
                        Message message = Message.obtain();
                        message.obj = "download ok";
                        handler.sendMessage(message);
                }
            }else {
                Log.e("SERVICE START", "false");
                return;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

When I run stopService in Activity Class, service calls the onDestroy function, but Timer still lives on.

How can I destroy the timer task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Handler and on destroy remove callback task

```
    TimerTask scanTask;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer t = new Timer();

    scanTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(task);
        }};
    t.schedule(scanTask,  5000, 20 * 1000);

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            //START YOUR JOB
            (new FetchData()).execute();

    }
};





@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("SERVICE STOP", "true");
    startService = false;
    checkTask.cancel();
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
    handler.removeCallbacks(task);

}

public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
           funcCheckInvoice();
    }
}
```

Comment: in void run in task Runnable, i using httpclient.excute .. and i get error .. :( ,, thank for help

Comment: is posible using asynctask from background service

Comment: Yes. If your Service just get data and then close then best practic is to use asynctask on activity. for more info see 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957775/android-asynctask-vs-service)

Answer (score 0):

You have started your Service as START_STICKY which could be the reason why
you can't stop the service.

Below is the [definition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) of START_STICKY.

> Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this
>   service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state
>   but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to
>   re-create the service. Because it is in the started state, it will
>   guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after creating the
>   new service instance; if there are not any pending start commands to
>   be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent
>   object, so you must take care to check for this.
>
> This mode makes sense for things that will be explicitly started and
>   stopped to run for arbitrary periods of time, such as a service
>   performing background music playback.

Try using START_NOT_STICKY

You also need to change the way you are calling cancel as you are calling
scheduleAtFixedRate.

```
private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduleTaskExecutor;
private ScheduledFuture schedule;
...
scheduleTaskExecutor = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
schedule =  scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(checkTask, 5000, 20 * 1000);


@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
  super.onDestroy();
  startService = false;
  checkTask.cancel();

  schedule.cancel(true);

}
```

Comment: timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(checkTask, 5000, 20 * 1000); is a void function .. schedule is a ScheduledFuture object .. can't use = .

Comment: sorry. I did not notice the Timer. Use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. modified my answer. :)

Comment: thank for help but httpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); is still alive :(

Comment: how did you start and stop the service? Did you use the START_NOT_STICKY? I am running your code in my PC and it is working fine with the modifications I suggested.